# Null Pointer Exception Аннотация @Autowired Spring

Tags: java, spring, аннотации

Никак не могу разобраться с тем, как работает аннотация @Autowired в Spring.
Итак, допустим, у меня есть вот такой интерфейс Interface1:

```
public interface Interface1 {
String getString();
}
```

У него есть всего один метод.
Следующий класс, являющийся @Service, реализует этот простой интерфейс:

```
@Service
public class Interface1Impl implements Interface1 {
    public String getString() {
    return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Теперь я хочу использовать где-то экземпляр этого класса вместе с аннотацией @Autowired. Создаю вот такой вот класс Instance1:

```
@Service
public class Instance1 {

@Autowired
Interface1 field;

public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println(field.getString());
    }
}
```

Далее в методе main своего главного класса я делаю следующее:

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instance1 instance = new Instance1();
    instance.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Однако появляется NullPointerException из-за того, что field с аннотацией @Autowired остался без присвоенного значения. Я не понимаю, почему так, и в целом плохо понимаю, как в данной ситуации работает Spring. Пожалуйста, объясните мне, как можно исправить код, чтобы в методе main я смог вызывать методы instance.

Comment: А она и не будет у вас инициализироваться, вы ведь не запускаете само приложение спринга, а просто дергаете интерфейс

Comment: Я вижу, что не инициализируется, ну и спрашиваю, как мне именно с помощью Spring и аннотации иметь возможность обращаться к методам моего класса из main?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Магия" аннотаций Spring работает только внутри контекста Spring. Который вам нужно создать. Вот некоторое приближение того, что вы пытаетесь сделать в `main`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.package")
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainClass.class);
        Instance1 inst = ctx.getBean(Instance1.class);
        inst.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Но в Spring-приложениях впринципе не принято делать никакую логику в `main`, кроме какой-то базовой инициализации самого Spring, т.к. этот код лежит за пределами контекста приложения.

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь подробное объяснение!